# How can I get Handles of child's HWNDS?

Tags: c++, windows

How can I get Handles of child's HWNDS?

E.g. I have window named "S1Window", its have controls(static texts, login boxes, etc.)

I need Handle of one login box

I tried

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChilds(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char class_name[80];
    char title[80];
    GetClassName(hwnd, class_name, sizeof(class_name));
    GetWindowText(hwnd, title, sizeof(title));
    std::cout << "Window title: " << title << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Class name: " << class_name << std::endl << std::endl;
    return TRUE;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HWND hnd=  FindWindowA("", "S1Window");
    EnumChildWindows(hnd, EnumChilds, 0);
}
```

But I get all windows opened

Comment: `But I get all windows opened` This means `FindWindowA` call failed and returned `NULL`, which you are blindly passing on to `EnumChildWindows`. The documentation for the latter states: "If this parameter is `NULL`, this function is equivalent to `EnumWindows`." Which is what you observe.

Comment: Are you sure that "HWND hnd" is not NULL?

Comment: It should be `FindWindowA(0, "S1Window");` not `FindWindowA("", "S1Window");` and check for return value as mentioned before.

Comment: thanks, now i use FindWindowA(0, "S1Window"); I've set breakpoint on callback, but callback doesn't executing(hwnd not null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you should pass NULL as lpClassName argument instead of empty string. Try this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HWND hnd =  FindWindowA( NULL, "S1Window" );
    if( hnd == NULL ) {
        return 1;
    }
    EnumChildWindows( hnd, EnumChilds, 0 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but now callback doesn't executing(hnd not null)

Comment: @wdbn I've been tested this code and it work fine. Maybe "S1 Window" doesn't contain any child? Check this code on other windows.